# Ibatis parameter initialization issue

Tags: sql, parameter-passing, ibatis, sqlexception

My application is having an exception about initialization of a parametermap into an sql  statement. The error is :

```
Caused By: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
--- The error occurred in /com/***/cusman/cusbilman/postpaid/main/product/data/ibatis/sqlMap/THSSqlMap.xml.
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
--- Check the invoicing.invoice.ths.paymentInfoMap.
--- Check the statement (query failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(MappedStatement.java:201)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.MappedStatement.executeQueryForList(MappedStatement.java:139)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:567)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForList(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:541)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForList(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:118)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate$3.doInSqlMapClient(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:298)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:209)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.executeWithListResult(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:249)
        at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.queryForList(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:296)
```

The definitions are totally persistent which each other(java side and the xml side I mean).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The problem is, oracle has not a stack trace type definition for errors. I was using a function in a select, but my db user had not got the grant to execute it, so Stupid Oracle tried to run it like, the function name is a column name. So it could not find a column name like it. So it hide the real problem...